# log4net for IIS WCF service with separate config

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, log4net

I want to use log4net for a WCF Service that is hosted in IIS.

But to change settings easily, I want to use a separate config file.

So I added to the Web.Config (and App.config of the WCF Service library)

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net_config" value="log4net.config" />
</appSettings>
```

But this leads to the current directory of IIS, which is

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
```

And there will never be my log4net.config file.

But I want to configure log4net something like

```
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4net_config"];
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(configFile);
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fileInfo);
```

How can I configure a directory that fits this needs?

Comment: why are you creating separate config file for logging (i.e log4net)?

Comment: Because it will be watched by log4net, so if I change it, I can see the changes without restarting the service.

Comment: For that purpose, why don't you go with XML? and maintain settings there only

Comment: At the moment I do not see how XML will solve that issue.

Comment: check http://adarkmouse.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/configure-log4net-in-wcf/                                                             (check point 4) I am not a fan of incorporating other configurations to my main Web.config so I will keep the log configuration in separate file: log4net.xml

Comment: this is exactly what I want to do, despite the name of my file not being .xml AND: My service is hosted in IIS, so a simple <file value="service.log" /> will not work. This is the problem in the question here.

Comment: Did you checked and implemented with points mentioned under above link. It should work.

Comment: If not configuring any path for the log4net config (xml), then it searched in the current directory (which is in my case C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ ) where no config is. So, this does not work for me. Perhaps I have to do something about it, hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you could put full path to your log4.net config file.

Secondly you can use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath` for example to resolve path like `"~/log4net.config"`

Comment: It is SO you don't need to thanks. Just +1 or mark response as answer

Comment: I used: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/") and combined path and configured filename. Works perfectly!